# ViewModel comes as null from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my code as below.Can somebody help me in this I am not able to send model to view.

ViewModel class
`IEnumerable<CarList> MyCarPositions`.

In my view.

```
@model TestMVC.ViewModel.
foreach (var item in Model.MyCarPositions)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Brand)
}
```

My Controller

```
ViewModel carviewmodel = new carviewmodel();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{     
    carviewmodel.MyCarPositions = repository.GetCarPositions();
    return View(carviewmodel);     
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel carvmodel)
{
    // Here in httppost carvmodel comes as null.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `name` attributes without indexers which cannot be bound to your model. Its also generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. You need to generate the collection using a custum `EditorTemplate` for the type in your collection, or use a `for` loop.

You have not shown you models, but property `MyCarPositions` needs to be `List<T>` if using the `for` loop option.

```
@model TestMVC.ViewModel
@using Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyCarPositions.Count, i++)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyCarPositions[i].Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyCarPositions[i].Brand)
  }
  <input type="submit" .. />
}
```

This will generate the correct name attributes necessary for binding

```
<input type="text" name="MyCarPositions[0].Name" .... />
<input type="text" name="MyCarPositions[1].Name" .... />
<input type="text" name="MyCarPositions[2].Name" .... />
```

Side note: You should be initializing the model inside the controller method

```
// ViewModel carviewmodel = new carviewmodel(); remove this
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{     
  ViewModel carviewmodel = new carviewmodel(); // initialize it here
  carviewmodel.MyCarPositions = repository.GetCarPositions();
  return View(carviewmodel);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right away I can see a syntax error that might be causing your issue.

```
foreach (var item in Model.MyCarPositions)
        {
             @Html.TextBoxFor(x => item Name <--- missing a '.' and a closing bracket
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.Brand)
        }
```

Should be:

```
foreach (var item in Model.MyCarPositions)
        {
             @Html.TextBoxFor(x =>item.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.Brand)
        }
```

Comment: Thx dustiny sorry that was typo.But I am not able to get the model in my controller it's null.In view source.The html is generated like below,<input id="item_Name" name="item.Name" type="text" value="John" />